# How to set a VPN connection in nmcli?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, vpn, openconnect

I want to use `nmcli` to connect to a VPN that I typically use Cisco Annyconnect for.

I've installed `networkmanager-openconnect` package (in Arch) and now I want to use it through `nmcli`. However, `nmcli` interface seems too convoluted for me.

Looking at `nmcli c add help`, it should be something along these lines:

```
Usage: nmcli connection add { ARGUMENTS | help }

ARGUMENTS := COMMON_OPTIONS TYPE_SPECIFIC_OPTIONS SLAVE_OPTIONS IP_OPTIONS [-- ([+|-]<setting>.<property> <value>)+]
```

with:

```
TYPE_SPECIFIC_OPTIONS:
...
    vpn:          vpn-type vpnc|openvpn|pptp|openconnect|openswan|libreswan|ssh|l2tp|iodine|...
                  [user <username>]
```

But the explanation in the help message is too terse for me and I could not find any examples online.

**Can anyone who uses `nmcli` for similar purposes share their examples here?**

---

**Failed attempts**

There is an example configuration [here](http://www.panticz.de/create-anyconnect-vpn-connection-on-command-line-with-nmcli). Exploring the available man pages I did not find what `form:main:group_list=CLIENTGROUP` even suppose to do.

Fails with:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: No valid secrets
```

---

For those who look for the simplest possible option; you can use `openconnect` directly:

```
sudo openconnect my.vpn.gateway
```

And that works as long as you don't need to make it available for a non-sudoer. When that happens, the plot gets complicated around name resolution (see [here](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/nonroot.html)).

I would prefer `nmcli` to handle this.

Comment: Are you able to obtain a configuration file from your VPN service provider? For OpenVPN, `.ovpn` config files are usually provided by the VPN service.

Comment: No, it is not available to me.

Answer (score 1):

I can show you my configuration for a cisco anyconnect configuration on Debian 11.
The `.nmconnection` file is stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connetictions`.

```
[connection]
id=CONNECTION_NAME
uuid=528f01b5-111e-4f9c-848f-b3234c0d733a
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
permissions=

[vpn]
authtype=password
autoconnect-flags=0
certsigs-flags=0
cookie-flags=2
enable_csd_trojan=no
gateway=VPN_URL
gateway-flags=2
gwcert-flags=2
lasthost-flags=0
pem_passphrase_fsid=no
prevent_invalid_cert=no
protocol=anyconnect
stoken_source=disabled
xmlconfig-flags=0
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openconnect

[vpn-secrets]
autoconnect=yes
form:main:group_list=GROUP
form:main:username=USERNAME
lasthost=VPN_URL
save_passwords=yes
```

You have to replace `CONNECTION_NAME`, `VPN_URL`, `GROUP`, `USERNAME`.

I tried a lot and hard that days to make that working. So I am not sure how I did it. I am not aware anymore if I created that file in an text editor, via `nmtui` or via the NetworkManager-GUI. I never used `nmcli`. I assume I used the NetworkManager GUI to create the connection because `nmtui` is not able to handle VPN. Especially for `eduroam` there are a lot of examples around in the internet.

Comment: Where in the world can I find the specification of that file? It is not in `man NetworkManager`, not in `man NetworkManager.conf`, not https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-keyfile.html. Where do I find what is the difference between `localhost` and `gateway` and what is `GROUP`?

Comment: OK, some information is in `man nm-settings-keyfile(5)`.

Comment: But it's not very helpful. Many of these settings are missing. For example `form:main:group_list`. Where did you find the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I found the clue by running:

```
nmcli connection show CONNECTION_NAME
```

For an already working connection.

So here a piece of script to set up a VPN connection:

```
# Helper error function
fail()
{
    echo "$*" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

name="Connection Name"
gateway="my.gateway.com"
group_name="VpnGroup"
group_passwd="GroupSecret"
username="remoteuser"
local_user="localuser"

nmcli connection add con-name "$name" type vpn vpn-type vpnc ||
    fail "Unable to create the connection"

nmcli connection modify "$name" \
    "autoconnect" "false" \
    "connection.permissions" "user:$local_user" \
    "vpn.data" "IKE DH Group=dh2,
                IPSec ID=$group_name,
                IPSec gateway=$gateway,
                IPSec secret-flags=0,
                Local Port=0,
                NAT Traversal Mode=natt,
                Perfect Forward Secrecy=server,
                Vendor=cisco,
                Xauth password-flags=2,
                Xauth username=$username,
                ipsec-secret-type=save,
                xauth-password-type=ask" \
     "vpn.secrets" "IPSec secret=$group_passwd" \
     "ipv6.ip6-privacy" "0"
```